# Stripe API returns no source although there are some according to dashboard

Tags: stripe-payments

My stripe account is in test mode.

I request all sources (with cards) for a given customer using:

```
curl "https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_FWzlniSobJD2yO/sources" \
    -u sk_test_SECRET_KEY: \
    -G
```

I get the following response:

```
{
  "object": "list",
  "data": [

  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "url": "/v1/customers/cus_FWzlniSobJD2yO/sources"
}
```

You can see that 'data', that should contain the customer's payment sources, is empty.

The cards have been saved from the front with stripe.js using:

```
stripe.handleCardPayment(intentClientSecret, cardElement, {
    payment_method_data: {
        billing_details: {name: 'Firstname Lastname'}
    },
    save_payment_method: true
});
```

Cards appearing in customer's details in my dashboard:
[image: Cards appearing in customer details]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although the cards are listed in the dashboard and the documentation says the request in OP should allow you to retrieve all cards, cards attached to a customer through "save_payment_methods" are not part of his "sources" but of his "payment_methods". Both are different APIs serving the same purpose, the latest being the newest and recommended way of doing things.

They are accessible through:

```
curl "https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_methods?customer=cus_FWzlniSobJD2yO&type=card" \
  -u sk_test_SECRET_KEY: \
  -G
```